# Android Firebase : Huawei p8 push Notification is not shown in system when app is in background?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

According to [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive):

**When App is in foreground:**

`onMessageReceived` is called and I could show the push notification and do any process with data (No problem with me in this case).

**When App is in Background:**

Notification system tray will show the notification and once user clicks on the notification, the launcher activity is called and notification data will passed in the bundle to the launcher activity.

My problem is that, Notification system is not showing the notification when app is in background.

I am NOT using Firebase console, because I couldn't add **data** to notification payload. So I used RESTful client API, but it's still the same problem.

Request:

```
URL:https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Method type: POST
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization : key=AAAAFi0N5KM....
Body:

    {
     "priority" : "high",
     "notification" : {
         "body" : "This week’s edition is now available.",
         "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
         "icon" : "new",
         "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" ,
         "sound" : "mySound"

     },
     "data": {
         "title": "title " ,
         "body": "any vaslue " 
     },
     "registration_ids": ["fVNdKJsWtNQ:APA91bEJ...."]
}
```

Response:

```
{
 "multicast_id": 6105324374411246344,
 "success": 1,
 "failure": 0,
 "canonical_ids": 0,
 "results": [
   {
    "message_id": "0:1486655756341577%dc81f05ff9fd7ecd"
   }
  ]
 }
```

this technique is working when app is in foreground but when is in background its not working

**Android Code:**

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
}

private void sendNotification(String messageTitle,String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0 /* request code */, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500};

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.roshetta_logo_home)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE,1,1)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

**manifest**

```
  <service android:name=".Util.PushNotification.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".Util.PushNotification.MyFirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: On what device are you testing?

Comment: onMessageReceiveived won't be called in background since your payload has a notification tag. The default android system should handle the notification on it's own. Maybe it's an issue with the icon or sound ... try it without that

Comment: The code looks okay. Have you tried it on different devices and see if it's the same case?

Comment: @AL. i tried in samsung and its working but in  Huawei its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time we had issues on Huawei phones, it was because the app wasn't a "Protected app".

1. Go to the Settings
2. Scroll down and tap on Advanced settings
3. Tap on Battery Manager
4. Find Protected apps and select it
5. Find your app, and set it protected

Comment: Then how the other apps like inshort and dailyhunt are doing without settings change?

Comment: @syedjibharat did you find an answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Manifest file. Hope you will receive push notification without modifying your system settings.

```
<service android:name="com.jibarath.MyFirebaseMessagingServices"
        android:exported="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"></action>
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**stopwithtask=false** did the trick.

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try sending the notification with a

```
  to:
```

instead of

```
registration_ids
```

The docs advise us to registration_ids only if there is more than one recepient.

> registration_ids
>   String array
>   This parameter specifies a list of devices (registration tokens, or IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens.Use this parameter only for multicast messaging, not for single recipients. Multicast messages (sending to more than 1 registration tokens) are allowed using HTTP JSON format only.

Also as you stated, the onMessageReceived will not be called when the device is in the background and there is a notification tag inside the payload.

The system should be able to handle it on its own. Make sure that the icon and the sound are properly kept in proper folders.

If everything is fine, check if the device is in doze mode(api >= 23). high priority messages should wake the device from doze, but this might not work if the device manufacturer has tampered with android os or tweaked it.

If the notification is still not delivered, it can be a device specific bug. check on another device to confirm.

If all else fails do the following:

I would also suggest to just send a data payload instead of both notification and data. If you are targeting just android, it gives way more control of handling what type and when to show the notification.

Just the data payload will always work whether backgrounded or foregrounded. It will always trigger onMessageReceived.